# How can we test Jetpack Compose callback function on a click action?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The problem is:
We have a test case where we expect that a callback function was called in response to a click action in our Composable. How can we handle this test correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    var clicked = false

    testRule.setContent {
        YourComposable(
            onClick = { clicked = true },
        }
    }

    testRule.onNodeWithTag("YourButton")
            .performClick()
    assertTrue(clicked)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you understand [state hoisting](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting),[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70608524/17314963) please try simple example:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonState(modifier : Modifier = Modifier,state : (flag : Boolean)->Unit) {
    var isFlag by remember{ mutableStateOf(false)}
    Button(onClick = {
        isFlag = !isFlag
        state(isFlag)
    },modifier) {
        Text(text = "text")
    }
}

setContent {
    var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column {
        ButtonState {
            flag = it
        }
        Text(text = "$flag")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @get:Rule
        val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()   
     

        @Test
        fun `should invoke callback on button click`() {
           val callback : () -> Unit = mockk()
    
            composeTestRule.setContent {
                YourComposable(
                    onClick = callback,
                )
            }
        
            composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("BUTTON_TAG").performClick()

            verify { callback() }
        }
```